# polymorphic_url(@resource) generating `new` action instead of `create` action path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic model. When generating the `polymorphic_url(@resource)` in the `form_for` like so, it is adding the wrong url.:

```
polymorphic_url(@resource)  # generates this
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/firm/accounts/sageview/resource_contents/new" method="post">
```

I need this:

```
polymorphic_url(@resource)
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/firm/accounts/sageview/resource_contents" method="post">
```

Here is `@resource` inspected:

```
#<ResourceContent id: nil, owner_id: 1, owner_type: "Firm::Account", metadata: {"type"=>"twitter"}, title: nil, description: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, article: nil>
```

This action is wrong, it should be going to `firm/accounts/sageview/resource_contents` but its adding new on the end of it. I would expect that action from `new_polymorphic_url(@resource)` but it I am not using the new_path.

Added routes:

```
firm_account_resource_contents    GET   /firm/accounts/:account_id/resource_contents(.:format) firm/accounts/resource_contents#index 
                                  POST  /firm/accounts/:account_id/resource_contents(.:format)                        firm/accounts/resource_contents#create
new_firm_account_resource_content GET   /firm/accounts/:account_id/resource_contents/new(.:format) firm/accounts/resource_contents#new
```

Does anyone see something wrong with this implementation?

Comment: Is `@resource` a new object?

Comment: @resource is indeed a new object, but I get the same path if I use `polymorphic_url(@firm_account, Resource.new)`

Comment: See my answer below, you should use `Resource` rather then `Resource.new`.

Comment: that produces an error: `undefined method `merge' for #<Class:0x007ff50aaf2600>`

Comment: Oops, see my edit. The params should have been within an array.

Comment: no dice: 
`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/firm/accounts/sageview/resource_contents/new"`

Comment: Can you provide your routes file?

Comment: Wait a second, why are you generating the index path for a form? I bet that is why it is defaulting to the new (or create given the method='post') path.

Comment: As I'm sure you know in rails you post to /model(s), added the roues.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I have added a form example to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because `@resource` is a new object. I feel like there needs to be more to your method call to produce that path because you have a specified path. Try something like this instead:

```
polymorphic_url([@account, Resource])
```

Providing the Resource class rather then an object will provide the index path.

Here is an example within a form (tested on my local machine on a project I am currently working on).

```
<%= form_for Note.new, url: polymorphic_path([@parent, Note]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
<% end %>
```

Which produces:

```
    <form class="new_note" id="new_note" action="/listings/1/notes" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
      <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
      <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+Ir0iqknLczzgJWLBuzJFtLtxZP/L2iyciwc5dxVKak1AbbzDrEpncIzhioxEA4I5UKuKo/quOktgMuNHJwdxw==">
      <input type="text" name="note[content]" id="note_content">
    </form>
```

[See this for more information.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)

Comment: That was quite the battle. This is a correct answer and I appreciate your persistence.